# Laravel 5.5 nested controller and view

Tags: view, nested, laravel-5.5

Let's say I have an "Contact" entity, and I have built with model, controller, views. All CRUD operation works.
Now I want to add addresses to the contact. There may be more than address for the same contact, but each address belongs only to one contact. Any CRUD operation about an address is nested to a contact.

I have built the model, and so far so good. I have populated the database by hand and I want to implement the addresses.index nested to the contacts.show.

The Addresses controller method should be something like this:

```
public function index($ContactId)
{
    $addresses = Addresses::where("contact_id",$ContactId)->paginate(10);
    return view('addresses.index',compact('addresses',"$ContactId"))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Now I want to build the view, but I'm lost, because I can't find any useful example or tutorial (or they are for a very old version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I nest addresses completely within users, contacts, leads, companies, etc. including the view directories, so `users.address.index` would be the view path, for example.

The routes to access addresses are also nested. If it's a simple project with only user's having addresses, the url would be '/users/1/addresses` to list their addresses. A controller method to list the address would typically look like:

```
class AddressController {
    public function index(Request $request, User $user) {
        return view('users.addresses.index', ['addresses' => $user->addresses]);
    }
}
```

Resource routing makes this all easy, you only have two route file entries like so:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
Route::resource('users.addresses', 'AddressController');
```

If I have several models in an application that can have addresses, I make `Address` polymorphic and abstract out the above controller further.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Where did you learn to nest? I only find fragmented informations. What would be the structure and code of the views?

Comment: I mainly learned by looking through the API and source code, as well as finding examples online. Discussions such as [this one](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/nested-resources-controllers-structure) help give ideas also.